# Error when creat spring mvc project - the type org.springframework.web.servlet.HandlerExceptionResolver cannot be resolved

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I'm trying to creat first Spring MVC project with Spring Tool Suite as tutorials in Spring MVC Beginner Guides - 2nd. But when I creat class WebApplicationContextConfig and save, it inform an error "The type org.springframework.web.servlet.HandlerExceptionResolver cannot be resolved. It is indirect referenced from required .class files". How can I do to fix this error?

Answer (score 0):

That sounds like you are missing some dependencies in your pom.xml, which makes Spring not able to found all the classes it needs to run the application. Can you please share it here?